# Query 7 random products in rails, iterate through them, and recieve undefined method `each' string error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my taxons_controller I have the following:

```
 @taxon = Taxon.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
 @related_products = @taxon.products.offset(rand(Spree::Product.count)).limit(7).name
```

I've tested a form of this and it is pulling a random object, but when I put it in my show view:

```
    <ul>
      <%= @related_products.each do |related_product| %>
      <li><%= related_product.name %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
```

I get a NoMethodError in Spree/taxons#show

undefined method `each' for "Spree::Product":String
Extracted source (around line #41):

```
     <ul>
    41.   <%= @related_products.each do |related_product| %>
       <li><%= related_product.name %></li>
       <% end %>
    </ul>
```

I've been using the .each variation all over the place, i dont understand what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over a `string`, when you should be iterating over an `array`.

```
# Remove the .name at the end
@related_products = @taxon.products.offset(rand(Spree::Product.count)).limit(7).name
@related_products = @taxon.products.offset(rand(Spree::Product.count)).limit(7)
```